# Invariant form for the Implicit Function Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, implicit-function-theorem

I am trying to show an invariant form (by coordenates) of the Implicit function Theorem and, the point I am having trobule is, exactly, the begining: Is not clear for me that there is a subspace $S\subset \mathbb{R}^{d+k}$ $k$-dimensional where $Df(a_0)|_S$ is bijective. My assumptions are:

> Let $f:U\subset \mathbb{R}^{d+k} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ be a $C^\ell$ map, with $f(a_0)=c$ for some fixed $a_0 \in U$ and $Df(a_0) \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{d+k},\mathbb{R}^k)$ is surjective.

Could someone give me a tip?

Comment: @JesseMadnick it is $k$-dimensional, indeed. It was wrong at the definition of $Df(a_0)$. I've written $Df(a_0) \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{d+k},\mathbb{R}^d)$ instead of $Df(a_0) \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{d+k},\mathbb{R}^k)$. Now it's okay, I guess.

Comment: Okay, so you're asking a linear algebra question.  Given a surjective linear map $L \colon \mathbb{R}^{d+k} \to \mathbb{R}^k$, why is there a $k$-dimensional subspace $S \subset \mathbb{R}^{d+k}$ such that $L|_S$ is bijective?  For that, you might start by considering the kernel (or "null space") of $L$.

Comment: Clearly $Df(a_0)$ has $k$ linearly independent columns.

Comment: @Jesse Madnick, and how do you suggest I use it?

Comment: Well, first you might ask where $\text{Ker}(L)$ lives.  Then you might compute its dimension by using the Rank-Nullity Theorem.  Maybe you take a basis for $\text{Ker}(L)$ and extend it to the entire space.  Considering the geometry of the situation might also be a good idea.  Knowing that a linear map between spaces of the same dimension is injective if and only if it is surjective is helpful, too.

Answer (score 1):

Your question actually has nothing to do with analysis, it's purely linear algebra, and as such I think it's beneficial to phrase the situation such that we keep only the essential details:

> Let $V,W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces over a field $\Bbb{F}$, and $T:V\to W$ a surjective linear transformation. Then, there is a (not necessarily unique) subspace $S$ of $V$ such that the restriction $T|_S:S\to W$ is an isomorphism.

The proof is simple. You know that $\ker(T)$ is a subspace of $V$, and thus it has a complementary subspace. It doesn't matter which complement we choose, just take any one of them and call that $S$. So, we now have an (internal) direct sum decomposition $V=\ker(T)\oplus S$. Now, by definition of the kernel, it follows that
\begin{align}
T[S]= T[\ker(T)+S]=T[V]=W,
\end{align}
where the last equality is because $T$ is surjective by hypothesis. In other words, the restriction $T|_S:S\to W$ is surjective. It is also injective because
\begin{align}
\ker(T|_S)&=\ker(T)\cap S = \{0\},
\end{align}
where the last equality is by definition of $S$ being a complement to $\ker(T)$. Therefore, $T|_{S}:S\to W$ is indeed bijective (hence an isomorphism).

---

Some simple things to reflect on:

- Think about what exactly a choice of complementary subspace to the kernel means, and how that relates to row/column operations once you reduce everything to matrices.
- Also, why does a complementary subspace exist?

Answer (score 1):

One can be a little more explicit:

Since $\operatorname{rk} Df(a_0) = k$, we know that $Df(a_0)$ has $k$ linearly independent columns. Let the indices of these columns be $i_1,...,i_k$ and let $S = \operatorname{sp} \{ e_{1_1},...,e_{i_k} \}$, where $e_i$ is the $i$th unit vector. Then $Df(a_0)\mid_S$ is bijective.